# How to use custom extension in visual studio code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, fonts

I'm starting my journey in the HTML space so please forgive me in advance. I wanted to follow some videos to get a better feel for it and one of the videos I'm following is creating a resume on GitHub through VS Code

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fqqOzRn12A

@3:44 they type Boxicons & Google Fonts in and then it switches to  (in a yellowy green colour) which leads me to believe this is some sort of custom extension that is being called I have been searching for multiple ones that dont seem to do what happens here. Does anyone know which extension is being used here?

Thanks

Comment: Addendum to this: is CTRL / being pressed and <!-- Boxicons --> appears?

Answer (score 0):

Those are simply comments, they appear automatically if you press `ctrl + /`, or you can type them manually, also if you are highlighting text and press `ctrl + /` it will place that text inbetween the comments.

Comments are used by developers to help them better understand what the code does, by using comments, the text inside of them does not get rendered on the page; be aware that different languages use different ways of defining comments.

A couple examples are:

- `<!--  -->` in HTML (`<!-- example -->`)
- `//` in Javascript, C, C++ for one liners (`// example`)
- `/* */` can also be used in Javascript for multi-liners (`/* example */`)

As for the coloring, you can always use an extension called '[Better Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments)' and configure the layout to your liking by:

- Opening your settings
- Under user (or workspace, you can choose) clicking extensions
- Select 'Better Comments'
- Select 'Edit in settings.json'

This will open a new tab with the already existing customization in them, here you can customize each character to your liking or add new ones.